# Каким образом можно получить список файлов в телефоне?

Tags: android

[image: Каким образом можно получить список файлов в телефоне]

Каким образом следует получать список файлов в телефоне? Нужно добавить отснятую фотографию в базу данных программы.

```
ImageView imageView0 = findViewById(R.id.image_editing_0);
xValues.put("IMAGE0", imageView0....
```

Ну, или поменяйте вопрос. Не знаю как правильно сформулировать...

Answer (score 0):

Загрузка изображения из галереи

Предположим, у вас есть на экране компонент ImageView, и вы хотите загрузить в него какое-нибудь изображение из галереи по нажатию кнопки:

```
static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }
});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

Bitmap bitmap = null;
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

switch(requestCode) {
    case GALLERY_REQUEST:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
}
}
```